# get the client window logged name and domain name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am trying to get my clients windows Username which the client use it to log in to his PC.

I tried all ways using many topics but I could not succeed.

please take a look at this temp website, it is giving me the server logged in username and its domain name.

http://gpfat1.al-hajjaj.com/

I have used all these lines of codes :

```
Label4.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        Label5.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        Label6.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
        Label7.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        Label8.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        Label9.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        Label10.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
```

also, I have modified the web.config file and added this :

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

so is there any way to get the client logged username instead of the server logged in username ?

thanks and best regards

Comment: have you tried disabling anonymous authentication within your web project properties?

Comment: yes, I have done it